# How can I run a job when a title is one of the target titles in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I want to run a job when a new issue title contains a certain string.

This can be achieved with:

```yaml
jobs:
  my_job:
    name: My job
    if: contains(github.event.issue.title, 'Target Title')
```

But when there are multiple target titles, this becomes:

```yaml
jobs:
  my_job:
    name: My job
    if: contains(github.event.issue.title, 'Target Title1') || contains(github.event.issue.title, 'Target Title2') || contains(github.event.issue.title, 'Target Title3')
```

, which is not good for readability.

What I need is **to get the target title list from a file, and check whether an issue title contains any of the target titles.**

```py
# python
with open('target-titles.csv', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  target_titles = lines.split(',')

if any(target in issue-title for target in target-titles)
  run_job()
```

Is there a way to implement this in Github Actions?

Comment: You could have a script or an action set an output and then the `if` condition on the next job could check that output.

Comment: @rethab Would you explain more? Where do I keep which kind of script?